# D3: How can I avoid data to overlap the X axis by moving data up

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I just don't want the dots to hide my axis line. I've tried it hard to push it up but i can't. Do anyone knows how to do it? I don't want to change the scale as i don't want a -1 appearing in the Y axis, i just want to move up the 0.

http://s21.postimg.org/6atyxkzrb/Data_Overlap_Axis.png

Comment: Start the range (not the domain) of the y scale a bit above where the x axis is.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I tried it before but just adjusting plus/minus one values to the range. Now that you told me to try again the range i tried it with 20/30 values and it worked. 
Thanks a lot.